# Using In to pull results from a second query

Tags: sql

I have a database that stores Invoice details.  As you'd expect each detail for an invoice is listed in the database.  Some sample information:

```
Invoice#     Service_Type    Detail_Code
1234            1               AB
1234            2               DF
1234            5               ER
1235            1               AB
1236            1               AB
1236            2               DF
1237            1               AB
1238            1               AB
1239            1               AB
1239            3               DZ
```

I'd like to write a query to count the number of services where the customer had a service type of '1' and did not have a detail code of DZ or DF.  So in this case, my query results would be:

```
"3"
```

It would Count Invoice numbers:

```
1235
1237
1238
```

I'm not quite able to get that. Here is my query:

```
SELECT Invoice_Number
FROM Invoice_Detail_Tb
WHERE (Invoice_Number IN (SELECT Invoice_Number
                          FROM Invoice_Detail_Tb AS Invoice_Detail_Tb_1
                          WHERE (Service_type = '1')
                            AND (Invoice_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
                            AND (Store_Number = @storenumber)))
  AND (Detail_Code NOT IN ('DF', 'DZ'))
```

When I run this query, I constantly get "6" which is the total number of services with service_Type "1". What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using `EXCEPT`.

```
SELECT Invoice_Number
FROM  Invoice_Detail_Tb
where service_type = '1'
EXCEPT
SELECT Invoice_Number
FROM  Invoice_Detail_Tb
where Detail_Code IN ('DF', 'DZ')
```

Because you can't use `except`, you can use `not exists`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66bd7/3)

```
SELECT Invoice_Number --use count(*) if you only need count
FROM  Invoice_Detail_Tb t
where service_type = '1'
and not exists(select 1 from Invoice_Detail_Tb where invoice_number = t.invoice_number and
               Detail_Code IN ('DF', 'DZ'))
```

Comment: I tried using the "Except", but It's an old version of SQL and i'm met with an "Unsupported" exception when using "Except"

Answer (score 0):

It could be very simple to obtain unique invoice numbers when using DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Invoice_Number
FROM  Invoice_Detail_Tb
WHERE
    Service_type = '1'
    and Detail_Code NOT IN ('DF', 'DZ')
    and Invoice_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate 
    and Store_Number = @storenumber
```

And for count services:

```
SELECT 
    Invoice_Number,
    count(*) as services_Count
FROM  Invoice_Detail_Tb
WHERE
    Service_type = '1'
    and Detail_Code NOT IN ('DF', 'DZ')
    and Invoice_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate 
    and Store_Number = @storenumber
GROUP BY Invoice_Number
```

Comment: That's not how it works with a "detail" table like this.  It'll return all results with "service_type '1'"

Comment: My bad, missed conditions from inner subqueries. Changed answer.

Comment: If you run that query, It still returns all with a service_type 1.

Comment: I can't run query on real data to see results, so you should check `@startdate`, `@enddate` and `@storenumber` param values used to filter results - probally range becomes very wide and it seems and all possilbe service_type = 1 are returned.